# Python find and replace with NA for delimited text files

Tags: python, regex, na, csv

I'm pretty new to python. Say I have data in a (very large) delimited text file like this:

```
a|b|c|d|e

1|.|.|-|.

1.2|2.6|||1.7
```

Since the text file is really large, I want to read and write it line by line. I want to replace cells that are `.`, `-` or empty with a string, `NA`. Here's what I tried:

```
import csv

f = open('sample1_fixed.txt','wb')

targets1, new1 = ['|.|','|-|','||','| |'], '|NA|'

for line in open('sample1.txt', 'rb'):
    for target in targets1:
        if target in line:
            line = line.replace(target,new1)
    for target in targets1:
        if target in line:
            line = line.replace(target,new1)
    f.write(line + "\n")
f.close()
```

But I'm thinking there must be a better way, one that uses the delimiter? Also this solution doesn't pick up the instances at the ends and beginnings of the lines. Any ideas from better programmers out there?

Expected output:

> a|b|c|d|e
>
> 1|NA|NA|NA|NA
>
> 1.2|2.6|NA|NA|1.7

I also tried using the csv module and regex:

```
import csv
import re

f=open('sample1_fixed.txt','wb')

with open('sample1.txt','rb') as inputfile:
    read=csv.reader(inputfile, delimiter='|')
    for row in read:
        text = row[1]
        text = re.sub(r'^\.$','NA',text)
        text = re.sub(r'^-$','NA',text)
        f.write(text + '\n')
f.close()
```

but this only allowed me to write one column at a time and I'm not sure how to get them all in the output...

Comment: What's the expected output for the above input?

Comment: Have you looked at the built-in csv module? You can specify a custom delimiter.

Comment: One way is to use the csv.reader with a custom delimiter='|', and a helper function for replace_NAs(). I only just noticed you want NA-replacement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `csv.reader` with a custom delimiter='|', and a helper function for replace_NAs:

```
import csv

delim = '|'

def replace_NAs(row, NA_values=["", ".", "-"]):
    if x in NA_values:
        return "NA"
    else:
        return x

with open('infile') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=delim)
    for row in reader:
        transformed_row = [replace_NAs(x) for x in row]
        print delim.join(transformed_row)

a|b|c|d|e
1|NA|NA|NA|NA
1.2|2.6|NA|NA|1.7
```

Comment: Why it fails to print `NA` for the second?

Comment: @AvinashRaj: I only just noticed OP also wanted NA replacement on all fields. Done. Edited the title for clarity.